# wc_get_product in a none woocommerce page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, ajax

I am creating a new shortcode in which I want to show some details about a product in a review-like page.

If I got it right - I can only use `wc_get_product` if the current page is using the WooCommerce plugin. Since it's a post page it does not includes the WooCommerce plugin and hence I can't use the `wc_get_product`.

(Please currect me if I'm wrong - I'm here to learn :D )

Is there a way I can get a product details by it's id on a page?

Thanks!

***EDIT:***

I am using this code as a shortcode with an attribute:

```
<?php

// Add custom Theme Functions here
// 

function gear_guide_product_view( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '0'
    ), $atts );
    echo var_dump(wc_get_product($a["id"]));
    wp_register_script( 'load_product_info' , '/wp-content/themes/theme-child/js/test.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'load_product_info' );
    wp_localize_script( 'load_product_info' , 'ids' , $atts);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );

add_shortcode( 'fsg' , 'gear_guide_product_view' );
```

This calls the js script:

```
function load_product_info() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/theme-child/js/controllers/get_product_info.php',
        data: ids,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Failed to get data!");
        }
    });
}
load_product_info();
```

And that ajax function calls the following controller:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
        $product_id = $_POST["id"];
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        echo json_encode($product);
    } else {
        echo "Nothing to return!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

> If I got it right - I can only use `wc_get_product` if the current page
> is using the WooCommerce plugin. Since it's a post page it does not
> includes the WooCommerce plugin and hence I can't use the
> `wc_get_product`.
>
> (Please currect me if I'm wrong - I'm here to learn :D )

You are wrong :D.

There's a fundamental misunderstanding about how plugins work here. Pages don't 'include' plugins. Plugins are installed at the site level, so what's important is whether or not the plugin is installed on the *site*.

So there's no reason you couldn't use `wc_get_product()` wherever you wanted, as long as WooCommerce is installed. You can pass it an ID to `wc_get_product()` to get the product details on any page, like this:

```
$product = wc_get_product( 12 ); // Assuming the ID is 12.
echo $product->get_sku();
```

**EDIT:** Based on the edit to the question, the problem becomes obvious: The problem is that your `get_product_info.php` file is just a PHP file sitting on its own. It's not even loading WordPress, let alone WooCommerce. Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) for how to do AJAX in WordPress.

Comment: But when I am using 'wc_get_product' I am getting an undefined function error..

Comment: Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: I'll edit the question, will take me a few minutes

Comment: Edited the question with the code

Comment: Well the problem is that your `get_product_info.php` is just a PHP file sitting on its own. You're not even loading WordPress, let alone WooCommerce. Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) for how to do AJAX in WordPress.

Comment: FWIW, WooCommerce has a REST API, so you could always just use that to retrieve product information via AJAX: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks. A question came up as I read, If I do not do any changing to the database, I still need to use the nonce?